# PowerLine Communication using a Cypress CY8CPLC10 and a PIC32 µController

Tags: c, embedded, microcontroller, i2c, mplab

I'm trying to run a CY8CPLC10 IC in order to communicate via PLC but it doesn't seem to work at all:
I communicate with the IC via I2C communication, I do the right init sequence and I follow all the given instructions in the Datasheet and in the Application Notes in order to send a proper command to the IC but it doesn't want to start the communication at all.

The main problem is that the bit number 7 of the 0x05 register doesn't turn to 1 so the communication could not start.

Sometimes, the IC just stop considering the I2C clock resulting in a ticking clock from the µC with no answer from the Cy8CPLC10.

If you already worked with this IC, could you give me some suggestions in order to let it work?

I'm using MPLAB X 5.10 as IDE and a PIC32MX110F016B as µC

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I2C clock and data lines need to be pulled high. Do you have pull-up resistors?

Comment: Of course yes, the I2C works fine, I use it to read the EEPROM.
I have a scope connected to the I2C lines for debug purposes.